# How to install Java Media Framework (JMF) on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, jmf

After following these steps from the website

> If you are installing the JMF Performance Pack for Linux
>   Change directories to the install location.
>   Run the command % /bin/sh ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin

This was my results. If it means anything I have already installed java se 8.

I also tried unzip but without success.

tail: cannot open ‘+309’ for reading: No such file or directory

Extracting...

```
./install.sfx.6226: 1: ./install.sfx.6226: cannot open ==: No such file

./install.sfx.6226: 1: ./install.sfx.6226: ==: not found

./install.sfx.6226: 3: ./install.sfx.6226: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

chmod: cannot access ‘JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmstudio’: No such file or directory

chmod: cannot access ‘JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfregistry’: No such file or directory

chmod: cannot access ‘JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfinit’: No such file or directory
./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: 305: ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin: JMF-2.1.1e/bin/jmfinit: not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit the installer and change "tail" command

```
vim jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin
```

go to line 267 or search for "tail" command

change:

```
tail +309 $0 > $outname
```

to:

```
tail -n +309 $0 > $outname
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
sudo ./jmf-2_1_1e-linux-i586.bin
```